# How to download repository?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example,

http://code.in.tum.de/

provide many useful stacks.

What I know is go into each stack to use svn to checkout, but I want to download all of them in one instruction.

How to download this repository?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47280/how-to-download-repository?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-11-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a way that might achieve what you want, but it is not guaranteed to work or continue to work in the future and might depend on the institution for the reasons that @Lorenz mentioned.

The [rosdistro](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/) repository contains indexing information for all institutions. For fuerte see, [doc/fuerte](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/tree/master/doc/fuerte). This indexing information is provided by rosinstall files. If an institution has decided to put their releases in one rosinstall file, then you can get them all by directly using this rosinstall with rosws/rosinstall.

However, this is not guaranteed at all. rosinstalls might be named differently/split, etc. You could merge all rosinstalls into a huge one and only extract those from one instituion given you filter for the URL.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-02**:
Right. Good hint. While not all of our stacks are hosted on code.in.tum.de anymore, the rosinstall file that is used by the pre-fuerte indexer can be found [here](https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/rosinstall/tum-ros-pkg.rosinstall).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is not possible, there is not central rosinstall file or something that contains all repositories. And not all repositories are using svn, some are using git, and we have some internal repositories, too.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1